# .setValue is only executed when the script is finished

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

D
I have a problem with my Script.
 a part of my script:

```js
    var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A");
    var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B");

    a.getRange("A14").setValue("external File");
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    a.getRange("A14:C29").copyTo(b.getRange("A1:C15"), {contentsOnly:true});
    a.getRange("A14:C29").clearContent();
```

now my only problem is,the Value("external File") will not be set, my script set this value first when the script stops.
Is there a posible methode to solve it, pls hold it eZ im not that well at google script :-D

Comment: Have you tried using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`, after `setValue()`

Comment: lol, thank you. Solved my Problem :-D

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on [@Jack Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7465829/jack-brown)'s comment, when both writing to and reading from the Spreadsheet interface, Google Apps Script does not necessarily immediately perform the write - it will attempt to optimize calls over the Spreadsheet interface to minimize resources needed.
Using [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) instructs the Apps Script engine to perform any pending changes to the spreadsheet (writes, calculations of cell formulas due to newly-written data, etc).

OP's snippet would then be:

```
var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("A");
var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("B");

a.getRange("A14").setValue("external File");

// Force the above value to be written (and any cells that refer to A14 to update).
SpreadsheetApp.flush();

// Without flush(), Apps Script may wait until making these calls to perform the write.
a.getRange("A14:C29").copyTo(b.getRange("A1:C16"), {contentsOnly: true});
a.getRange("A14:C29").clearContent();
```