# setValue Google script function not setting values

Tags: google-apps-script, setvalue

I am using Google script to set value in sheet. Then there are formulas in sheet which got refreshed once value is set and then creating pdf. This script was working fine till last week but suddenly it has stopped working. Its just setting last value after loop is over. What is wrong in this script.

```google-apps-script
function myfunction() { 

    var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Store").getRange("A1:A400").getValues();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1guRQ0oePKFq9DgggbMwLKCk3yqEGphMe');
    Logger.log(range2);
    for (i=1;i<range2.length;i++ ){

        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Store").getRange("B2").setValue(range2[i][0]);

        var pdf = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs('application/pdf');

        var name2 = range2[i-1][0];
        var pdf2=folder.createFile(pdf);

        pdf2.setName(name2);
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091172/solved-setvalue-is-only-executed-when-the-script-is-finished

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
function myfunction() {
    var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Store").getRange("A1:A400").getValues();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1guRQ0oePKFq9DgggbMwLKCk3yqEGphMe');
    Logger.log(range2);
    for (i = 1; i < range2.length; i++) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Store").getRange("B2").setValue(range2[i][0]);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        var pdf = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs('application/pdf');
        var name2 = range2[i - 1][0];
        var pdf2 = folder.createFile(pdf);
        pdf2.setName(name2);
    }
}
```