# Function for saving range of data in google sheets sometimes copies blank cells, how to get it to pause and wait for source data to refresh?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

rephrase to clarify it's not a duplicate of existing question: Setvalue executes before the scripts that produce the data has finished pulling in the data. i.e. setvalue pastes blank cells because the source cells haven't calculated the data

I have the following function for copying data and appending to the bottom of the sheet. I combine this function with a time driven project trigger into order to save this data every day. 
However the source data that I wish to save from range "28SEP18!A1:K49" sometimes hasn't refreshed so the function just copies and pastes blank cells.

Is there something I can add to my function to get it to wait for all the formulas and functions in the source data to refresh before it copies and pastes the data? i.e. before setvalues()

```
function saveData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var optiondata = sheet.getRange("28SEP18!A1:K49").getValues();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 49, 11)
          .setValues(optiondata);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.setValue is only executed when the script is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091172/setvalue-is-only-executed-when-the-script-is-finished)

Comment: Okay it’s not a duplicate, but the use of SpreadsheetApp.flush() was the key to the earlier question.”_Using SpreadsheetApp.flush() instructs the Apps Script engine to perform any pending changes to the spreadsheet (writes, calculations of cell formulas due to newly-written data, etc)._”  That sounds a lot like the problem that you have, and the solution you need.